# Rendering tangent space normal maps in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normal-map

**Version:** Blender 2.82a

**Issue:**
Create a composite node setup to render a tangent space normal map.

**Current setup:**

[image]

Node setup I have right now after lots of googling(still doesn't work correctly):

[image]

What it produces:

[image]

Anything in the scene that is on the Z axis seems to produce invalid colors for a tangent space map. While X and Y are producing good results. As you can see from the example with a cylinder on a plane. Although even the base color seems a bit off. Not sure.

Here's an example of the the type of result I'm looking for, just for a different object:

[image]

Any ideas of how to go about this would be greatly appreciated, even if it's a different approach than I am using now. Thanks!